# How to get ID, Rel, and Text of moved node and its new parent - JSTREE v 3

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jstree

**Target:**
I am using "dnd" and "html_data" plugin to drag and drop nodes. In order to save the new order in the database, I need to know the ID and the new parent ID of the moved node.

**Issue:**
I can't seem to get to the actual ID of the moving node. When I try these

```
alert(data.node.id);
alert(data.parent);
```

I get the id's in jx_y format, which is the id generated by jstree (that I can see in the output source structure). I want the real "id" and "rel" of the node. These "id" and "rel" are passed to li element while I create the tree structure from the database. eg:

```
<ul>
<li id='from db row[id]' rel='again from db row[parent id]'>node title</li>
....children continues.....
</ul>
```

I have tried result obj, but it is giving me "undefined error

```
data.rslt.obj.attr("rel") or data.rslt.obj.attr("id")
```

In firebug I can see the object using

```
console.log(data)
```

which displays the detail information about the nodes. this may help me, but am not sure how to actually access that or display that in alert or for debugging purposes.

```
new_instance -> model -> data -> li_attr
```

**Question:**
I just want to be able to get the real ID of the node and its new parent ID so that I can use ajax to update the info in the database. These ID would be the one(retrieved from my mysql db) which I fed to the tree while creating it.

I am using html_data after the road block I encountered using JSON plugin to implement jstree, see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127782/jstree-issue-populating-jstree-data-using-mysql-and-php

**Details:**
Perhaps I was not very clear. Here is the list of my baby steps so far:

1) I am using jstree v 3/php/mysql to create a tree for hierarchcical structure

2) I am using html_data, and dnd plugin of jstree to accomplish this task.

3) The tree structure is being displayed perfect using ul, li format and data being populated through the database.

```
echo "<li rel='". $row['parent_ID'] . "' id='". $row['ID'] . "'><a>". $row['title']. "</a>"
```

4) Drag and Drop is working perfect too

5) Now I want the drag and drop persist. For that I need to know the id for the moved node, and its new parent node. The id's and rel are provided to the tree while populating from the database. I just want those id's when I move a node to a new location during my bind operation.

```
$("#mytree").bind('move_node.jstree', function(e, data) {

    console.log(data) ;

    alert("moving node id " + data.node.id);
    alert("moving node rel " + data.node.rel);
    alert("new parent id " + data.parent);

    // once I get the new parent id, and id of the node, 
    // i will use ajax call to update the database


}) ;
```

let me know, if my question is still not clear.

Comment: Your description is vary vague. Can you post more of your code?

Comment: updated my question with a bit of details

Comment: So just read `data.parent.id`?

Comment: data.parent gives me jx_y, where x and y is the location of node generated by jstree (I see that from the source code). data.parent.id gives me "undefined". I want the real ID which I passed to the node while I created it. e.g. during my tree creation the node id and rel is passed as: echo  "<li rel='". $row_inner['parent_ID'] . "' id='". $row_inner['ID'] . "'><a>". $row_outer['title']. "</a>"

Comment: I have been able to implement jstree with db interactivity and saving the state in the database. I have used htlml_data plugin, no success with json so far though. At any rate, if anyone wants help going this route, let me know. I can help you create tree structure from db, ability to drag and drop, and persist changes using db. Kudos to the create of JS Tree, extraordinary library !!!